# Error when trying to record a video using react-native-image-picker

Tags: ios, react-native, video, react-native-image-picker

I have been using react-native-image-picker for upload a certain recorded video and hence used the launchCamera method to open the camera to record a video in real time. However I am getting an error in IOS (this works fine in Android) as follows,

**[CAMCaptureEngine] Received a session runtime error notification : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12983), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x282a04e70 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12983 "(null)"}}**

This is the code I've used,

```
launchCamera({mediaType: "video", 
              durationLimit: 300, 
              quality: 0.4}, 
async (data) => {
// some logic
}
```

Guidance to recover this error is much appreciated.

Comment: This error usually comes when you are trying to use the camera when screen sharing. Did you try closing all the background applications which was using the camera?